# convert an image into color pencil sketch in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I want to convert an image to a color pencil sketch using OpenCV. And I have read the page [I want to convert an image into pencil sketch in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675151/i-want-to-convert-an-image-into-pencil-sketch-in-opencv)
.The effect which I seek is like http://www.showandtell-graphics.com/photosketch.html
I used the color dodge by code

```
b_d = (b_2==255? 255: min(255, b_1*255 /(255- b_2)));        
g_d = (g_2==255? 255: min(255, g_1 *255/(255- g_2)));             
r_d = (r_2 ==255? 255: min(255, r_1 *255/(255- r_2)));
```

It seems work not very well.
PLS help.

Answer (score 8):

The overall procedure is detailed in the link you gave us, so you need 3 images to achieve this effect.

Make a copy of the original image and convert it to [grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977647/176769).

Make a copy of the grayscale image and [invert](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not) this image.

At this point, **image #1** is the original, **image #2** is grayscale, and **image #3** is the inverted image.

Then, apply the *[color dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925219/176769)* to image **#3** (making it white) and [execute the blur](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur). This alone will give you the pencil sketch effect in grayscale.

If you want the final result to be colored, you will have to [blend](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) image #3 with image #1.

Looking for information on blending? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460287/176769), [this](http://pt.scribd.com/doc/88285388/21/Adding-blending-two-images-using-OpenCV) and [this](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/).

Comment: You mean:  1.cvCvtColor(source_img, gray_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);2.cvNot(gray_img, imgtemp);  3.execute dodge like color_dodge(dst_img, gray_img, imgtemp);  4.cvSmooth(dst_img, result_img, CV_GAUSSIAN)?????  How to solve the channel problem among those image? I mean the channel of gray is 1

Comment: @karlphillip : what is this dodge operation, mathematically (for grayscale image and color image)

Comment: @karlphillip - I am not using openCV but can above applied to regular java code? I am confused by color dodge. Which two images you use for color dodge? Is it image#2 and image #3? If i use those i get all white no image?

Comment: @NoviceMe The Color Dodge blend mode divides the bottom layer by the inverted top layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Dodge_and_burn). According to the [original link](http://www.showandtell-graphics.com/photosketch.html), those are: the colored image and the inverted.

Comment: This become not as good as display in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dumplingsandwich.pencilsketch. I want this type of sketch exactly. so please help me

Comment: If anyone ends up putting together the complete code, post it please