# Processing previous and current frame continuously

Tags: opencv

Basically,

1. I have set a reference line at particular place of the image say at height/2
2. I calculate the total white pixel at that line

The frame keep going continuously. Then, how can I read/get back the value of total white pixel from previous frame and current frame continuously?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question :s, save the value to a variable ?

Comment: Which part is not clear? I just want to get back the value from previous frame and get current frame so that I can compute division of it. What should I do actually? 
This is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974239/opencv-rgb-to-gray, see the post by karlphilip. Am I suppose to do that in order to get the value previously and current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to hold a member with the prev value. 
 assuming `readPixel()` function reads the total white value, `curr` is the current value, and `prev` is the previous value. this is example pseudo-code:

```
prev = curr = readPixel; //avoid division by zero
for(;;)
{
    curr = readPixel();
    value = curr / prev;
    prev = curr;
}
```